# Chart.js - Bezier curve between points instead of around

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I want to customize the rendering of my Chart.js line graph. Right now the line is curved (using default Bezier spline curves). This default implementation make the curves around the data points and not between them.  This makes the graph appear to go below zero, which it does not.

Is is possible to get a bezier curve between the points instead of around?

If I disable the curves with lineTension = 0, I get straight lines but I like the curviness.

[image: chartjs-tension]